# Jquery - remove li containing link

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a link inside a `<li>` element and want the `<li>` element to be removed when the link is clicked. Here is my code:

```
<li id='i80'>
 <div class='singleitem'>
  <img src='/css/images/image.png' width='30' height='30' />
  <div id='listtext'><h1>Title</h1></div>
  <a class='delete' id='80' href='#'></a>
  <div id='helper'></div>
 </div>
</li>
```

And my Jquery code:

```
$(".delete").click(function(e){
 var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
 e.preventDefault();
 $.post("/add/delete.php", { iid: del_id } ,function(data){
  if(data.status == 'deleted');
   {
     $(this).closest("li").remove();
   }
 });
});
```

The ajax is working fine and the 'deleted' status is being sent back correctly, however, that one line that involves removing the parent `li` just doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I've noticed that new list items I've added dynamically to my existing `ul` don't work here. Is that because this just loads when the page loads initially and then won't work with with dynamically updated content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(this) object within ajax block isn't $(".delete") object. You will need to do something like this:

```
$(".delete").click(function(e){
 var $del_button = $(this);
 var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
 e.preventDefault();
 $.post("/add/delete.php", { iid: del_id } ,function(data){
  if(data.status == 'deleted');
   {
     $del_button.closest("li").remove();
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: You did it! Thanks a lot for the quick reply, it works perfectly now. I'll mark this as answered as soon as the time limit is up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".delete").click(function(e){
 var del_btn = $(this);              // cahed
 var del_id = del_btn.attr('id');
 e.preventDefault();
 $.post("/add/delete.php", { iid: del_id } ,function(data){
  if(data.status == 'deleted');
   {
     del_btn.closest("li").remove(); // used
   }
 });
});
```

---

**EDIT**
to fit an additional issue asked by the OP.

Use the `.on()` method like:

```
$(".singleitem").on('click', 'a.delete', function(e){
 var del_btn = $(this);              // cahed
 var del_id = del_btn.attr('id');
 e.preventDefault();
 $.post("/add/delete.php", { iid: del_id } ,function(data){
  if(data.status == 'deleted');
   {
     del_btn.closest("li").remove(); // used
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot for the quick answer!

Comment: @nbu - Yeah :) I see I share the same answer with *mask8*. Thanks to you. Happy coding!

Comment: one more question: i've noticed that new list items i've added dynamically to my existing ul don't work here. is that because this just loads when the page loads initially and then won't work with with dynamically updated content?

Comment: I can reedit my answer to make that work. You can improve/refresh your question too

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem to be working for me. My code is all within `$function(){}`, is that okay?

Comment: Totally fine. But I would use: `(function($){ /*all your jQuery here at the bottom of page before </body> tag*/ })(jQuery);`

Comment: and Don't use NUMBER as a starting `id` value/name like you have in `<a class='delete' id='80' href='#'></a>`

Answer (score 0):

try $(this).parent().remove();

(although it feels like sawing off the branch you are sitting on..)

Comment: have you tried it? your code should work - but (seeing as it doesn't) does mine ?

Comment: I don't need to, I know what is the problem and what `closest` and `parent` do...

Comment: play nice :-) just trying to help... looking the new answers I see it too!

Comment: Just wanted to point out the `closest` is just like `parent` but it will traverse the DOM until it find it ancestor, while `parent` just take the node direct father. Cool?

Answer (score 0):

try the following, you need to reference the parent

```
$(this).parent().remove()
```